# JS Date() returns NaN, even with toString()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to calculate the age of a user:

```
// Get today's date
var today = new Date();
var dd = today . getDate();
var mm = today . getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today . getFullYear();

if( dd < 10 ) {

    dd = '0' + dd;

} 

if( mm < 10 ) {

    mm = '0' + mm;

} 

/*
* Calculate the age in days
*/
var minimum_age_in_days = 6574;

var date_of_birth_formatted = new Date( year + '/' + month + '/' + day );
today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;

var difference = today - date_of_birth_formatted;

var difference_in_days = difference / 100 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 10;

console . log( difference ) . toString();
console . log( difference_in_days ) . toString();

if( difference_in_days < minimum_age_in_days ) {

    $( "#formModal" ) . show();
    $( "#overlay" ) . hide();
    alert( "You're not 18 years old" );

}

else {

    // Hide first modal
    $( "#formModal" ) . hide();

    // Show second modal
    $( "#overlay" ) . show();

}
```

The two console.log()'s return `NaN`, while I've tried converting them to strings so I can do an if() statement. However, because these variables (`difference` & `difference_in_days`) have a value of `NaN`, so the code breaks. How can I convert these values, so the code doesn't break?

Comment: Do you really put spaces between objects, the `.` and the method? :S Anyway, I suspect if you do `var today = new Date(); console.log(today);` you'll see normal output.

Comment: Maybe you can use moment to perform such operations...check `MomentJs`: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Several problems here, you cant subtract strings (hence `NaN`). They both need to be `Date`s. You also never defined `year`, `month`, or `day`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Those are defined before this code, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @erol_smsr You need to give reproducible code, we can't just assume they happened to be defined. Again the problem is you can't subtract strings, so yes that's the issue. `string - Date = NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is coming from these two lines:

```
var date_of_birth_formatted = new Date( year + '/' + month + '/' + day );
today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;

// examine them:
typeof date_of_birth_formatted  // returns "object"
typeof today // returns "string"
```

You're going to get `NaN` by subtracting a string from a Date object.  Rather than all the extra work you're doing to get today's date, try just using a new Date directly.  Your code could then be simplified to:

```
var date_of_birth_formatted = new Date( year + '/' + month + '/' + day );

var difference = new Date() - date_of_birth_formatted;

var difference_in_days = difference / 100 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 10;

console.log( difference ).toString();
console.log( difference_in_days ).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line 25: 
`today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;`
You can solve your problem by deleting this line.

**Reason:** The above line (25) changes your today object to string type. `typeof today` is `string`. While `typeof date_of_birth_formatted` is `object`. Subtracting object from string is returning `NaN`.